# Redundant 'using' statements?

Tags: c#, linq, using

Looking at a few solutions of programming challenges on [CodeAbbey](http://www.codeabbey.com/), I've noticed many C# solutions implementing the following at the beginning of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Aside from `System`, it appears the statements are not used. They are even implemented for simple looping programs. Ideone examples: [1](http://ideone.com/1gt94D) [2](http://ideone.com/2XLX5R) [3](http://ideone.com/s5snYE)

Are these statements in fact needed for the code to function, or are they added as a matter of habit?

Comment: Who told you to include those `using` , remove, see if are able to compile or build. By the way, those links in `Examples` are not accessible.

Comment: Your links are not visible by anyone unless they log into an external website.  Can you post an example?

Comment: @Davin Tryon I have updated my post.

Comment: @Arindam Nayak I have updated my post.

Comment: Most meaningful C# programs pretty much need the first three... But in general it's better to remove unused `using` statements....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in Visual Studio 2013, with a .NET 4.5 project, you *Add New Item*, *Class*, you get this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace (yournamespace)
{
    class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

that includes those `using`. If you don't need them, you can remove them (or you can more easily right click, *Organize Usings*, *Remove Unused Usings*)

If you then discover that you need them, it is quite easy to right-click on an error, *Resolve*, *using (something)*.

**Note that there is an exception**: extension methods. You can't "automagically" *Resolve*, *using (something)* with extension methods. For this reason, removing the `using System.Linq` can be a pain, because then if you use LINQ you have to re-add it "manually" (by typing `using System.Linq`).

Comment: That would explain it. I'm using Xamarin Studio and it's not the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is common for an IDE (like Visual Studio) to auto generate a list of `using` statements at the top of a new file.

These should be cleaned in order to de-clutter the code file if they are not used. However, I assume the compiler will get rid of them during compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Redundant `using` directives at the top are not used. However, they are entirely harmless, provided that the corresponding DLLs are referenced in your project for some other reason.

Redundant `using` directives most often come from code templates. Many programming shops would set up such templates for internal use, so that the top parts of their source files look consistent.

Removing redundant `using` directives simplifies code maintenance in situations when you need to remove a referenced DLL from your module. In this situation a `using` directive would trigger a compile error even when it is unused, so I would recommend removing them. With tools available for automated maintenance of `using` directives it become very easy to maintain the minimal set of `using` at the top of your program, so removing unused directives does not require a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

They're typically added as part of templates when you create a new class file in your project. You can safely remove the ones you don't use. Some tools (ReSharper, Roslyn analyzers, etc) will show you the `using` statements that are not used and offer to remove them.